# Javascript the break condition for recursive function iterating over JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, break

I am unsure how I would examine and create the break condition for this recursive function. At the moment the function freezes the browser (seems to loop endlessly).

I am trying to generate a series of nested unordered lists based on data provided in the list object.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mzckoc7s/

```
var list = {
    "primary": [{
        "item": "item 1"
    }, {
        "item": "item 2",
        "secondary": [{
            "item": "item secondary 1"
        }, {
            "item": "item secondary 2"
        }, {
            "item": "item secondary 3",
            "secondary": [{
                "item": "item inner secondary 1"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "item": "item 3"
    }]
}

function items( obj ) {
    var output = '<ul>';
    for ( i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ) {
        output += '<li>' + obj[i].item + '</li>';
        if (typeof obj[i].secondary != 'undefined') {
            items( obj[i].secondary );
            break;
        }
    }
    output += '</ul>';
    return output;
}
```

The final result is supposed to be this:

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2
        <ul>
            <li>item secondary 1</li>
            <li>item secondary 2</li>
            <li>item secondary 3
                <ul>
                    <li>item inner secondary 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: is it a given data structure or can you change it a little bit to group the same level to only one array?

Comment: the structure can't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested approach be iterating the keys of the object and the possisble arrays. Then build the output and respect not given children.

```js
function getItems(object) {
    var output = '';
    object && typeof object === 'object' && Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k === 'item' || !object[k]) {
            return;
        }
        output = output || '<ul>';
        output += (Array.isArray(object[k]) ? object[k] : [object[k]]).map(function (a) {
            return '<li>' + a.item + getItems(a) + '</li>';
        }).join('');
    });
    output += output && '</ul>';
    return output;
}

var list = { primary: [{ item: "item 1" }, { item: "item 2", secondary: [{ item: "item secondary 1" }, { item: "item secondary 2" }, { item: "item secondary 3", secondary: { item: "item inner secondary 1" } }] }, { item: "item 3" }] },
    result = getItems(list); 

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I like this but this method requires that each key IS an array which could potentially not happen. if you check out var list_two in this fiddle at the bottom of the javascript file https://jsfiddle.net/mzckoc7s/2/ you will see valid json but "item inner secondary 1" does not get considered

Comment: none the less, I find your suggestion very helpful -- if (Array.isArray(object[k]) || object[k] === Object(object))

Comment: I'll take you up on this :) I found other approaches but this one seems pretty robust to me. By the way, I can't rely on checking for existence of a particular key.. But you helped me build something usable. Thank you.